# How to maintain IK chain angle to target?

Tags: armature, bones, parent, inverse-kinematics

I've got a robot assembly arm (http://sendvid.com/ze9l813s) set up with an inverse kinematics solver, but I don't know how to keep the end bone from rotating. I need that bone to remain perpendicular to the Z axis, and to the target, while it is moving. I don't want to use rotation constraints, I just want the IK chain to have the end bone remain totally perpendicular to the ground. How do I do this with inverse kinematics?

If you're having trouble visualizing it, here's a video of what an assembly arm is supposed to work like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J23oqwyN9-A

The arm can move *straight* up and *straight* down, not in some kind of weird bendy arc like the Inverse Kinematics rig is doing.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, I think this kind of setup would be the simplest solution:

[image: Robotic Arm Rig]

The main point is to disable "Inherit Rotation" for the tip bone.

[image: Disable Inherit Rotation]

Extrude another bone from the root of the "Tip Bone" that will be the "IK Target", and clear its Parent (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> in Armature Edit Mode). It must not have a Parent in order to function properly as an IK Target.

[image]